# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I've got a column in one of my models that is nullable. It is nullable in the EDMX, and I've checked that it's nullable in the generated code. I've octuple-checked that it's nullable in the database. However, when I try to save an instance of the model with the column set to null, I receive the exception "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types." Most of the code involved here is either the Entity Framework code itself, or generated code. I have other nullable columns that do not seem to have this problem.

Has anyone run into anything like this? Googling around for things mostly reveals people who need to do `if (someSqlValue == DBNull.Value)` with manual ADO recordsets, but since this is EF interacting with DBNull, there's nowhere in my code that could possibly need to check this.

Unfortunately, I cannot share the code with this, and as I mentioned, most of my nullable columns do not exhibit this problem, so I am not confident in my ability to reproduce the problem in a small test case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the type in your EDMX matches the type in your database (i.e. that you aren't trying to stuff a null int SQL value into a nullable DateTime field or something like that)?

Comment: I actually tried just putting a literal `null` into it, and it gave the error.

Comment: ... I'm not sure what you're referring to here.  I'm saying, regardless of the actual _value_ that you're dealing with, double-check the _type_ of the field/property in your Entity Framework mapping (both the .NET type and the SQL type specified in the mapping), and verify that it matches the type of the column in your SQL table.